# Updating d3js Datamap with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to learn to use [d3js datamaps](https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps) and I'm struggling with dynamic data.

Every example in the site uses some static data, written as a javascript object, but I need it to be dynamic.

I'm starting from a JSON file in which I've got some data, and I'm parsing them to create a new JSON that follows the `data` format of *datamaps*.

The output JSON is like this one:

```
{
ARG: {
    plays: 15768,
    fillKey: "LOW"
},
AUT: {
    plays: 31061,
    fillKey: "LOW"
},
AUS: {
    plays: 169478,
    fillKey: "LOW"
},
BEL: {
    plays: 65295,
    fillKey: "LOW"
},
BRA: {
    plays: 12602,
    fillKey: "LOW"
},
GBR: {
    plays: 731583,
    fillKey: "LOW"
},
ITA: {
    plays: 131569,
    fillKey: "LOW"
},
USA: {
    plays: 272685,
    fillKey: "LOW"
}
}
```

If I execute

```
map.updateChoropleth({ARG: {plays: 15768,fillKey: "LOW"},AUT: {plays: 31061,fillKey: "LOW"},AUS: {plays: 169478,fillKey: "LOW"},BEL: {plays: 65295,fillKey: "LOW"},BRA: {plays: 12602,fillKey: "LOW"},GBR: {plays: 731583,fillKey: "LOW"},ITA: {plays: 131569,fillKey: "LOW"},USA: {plays: 272685,fillKey: "LOW"}})
```

or if I instantiate the map with

```
data: {ARG: {plays: 15768,fillKey: "LOW"},AUT: {plays: 31061,fillKey: "LOW"},AUS: {plays: 169478,fillKey: "LOW"},BEL: {plays: 65295,fillKey: "LOW"},BRA: {plays: 12602,fillKey: "LOW"},GBR: {plays: 731583,fillKey: "LOW"},ITA: {plays: 131569,fillKey: "LOW"},USA: {plays: 272685,fillKey: "LOW"}}
```

it all goes fine, but this means using static hardcoded data and this is not what I need.

Until now I've tried some routes, with no success.

Writing the `data` property of the map object like this

```
data: function() { return parseJSON("json/world-top/latest.json")}
```

leads to nothing, and the same applies to

```
data: parseJSON("json/world-top/latest.json")
```

and

```
var jsonString = parseJSON("json/world-top/latest.json");
map.updateChoropleth(jsonString);
```

Where am I wrong?

EDIT:

The `parseJSON` function that I'm using is a function that I wrote to change my JSON data from

```
{
    "tracks": [{
        "date": "2014-05-11",
        "country": "ARG",
        "track_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/track\/3cHyrEgdyYRjgJKSOiOtcS",
        "track_name": "Timber",
        "artist_name": "Pitbull",
        "artist_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/artist\/0TnOYISbd1XYRBk9myaseg",
        "album_name": "Global Warming: Meltdown (Deluxe Version)",
        "album_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/album\/2F7tejLHzTqFq2XLol9ZGy",
        "artwork_url": "http:\/\/o.scdn.co\/300\/d096684f9d3fa3525421f2c4204f4e8e2cbba471",
        "num_streams": 50382
    },
    {
        "date": "2014-05-11",
        "country": "AUT",
        "track_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/track\/7b71WsDLb8gG0cSyDTFAEW",
        "track_name": "Summer",
        "artist_name": "Calvin Harris",
        "artist_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/artist\/7CajNmpbOovFoOoasH2HaY",
        "album_name": "Summer",
        "album_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/album\/0IGsZsrvIe5AQKvMmVobYq",
        "artwork_url": "http:\/\/o.scdn.co\/300\/ca67ba1425e4308104ecae9fc493f3ef96ceb72a",
        "num_streams": 32885
    },
    {
        "date": "2014-05-11",
        "country": "AUS",
        "track_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/track\/3oxO64VclwEDBoJWkeneBW",
        "track_name": "Fancy",
        "artist_name": "Iggy Azalea",
        "artist_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/artist\/5yG7ZAZafVaAlMTeBybKAL",
        "album_name": "Fancy",
        "album_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/album\/5oX3sr8ft9IwnI090Xf35t",
        "artwork_url": "http:\/\/o.scdn.co\/300\/d71d05ded1704bcf849465dd5e76e196847d1c0a",
        "num_streams": 201763
    },
    {
        "date": "2014-05-11",
        "country": "BEL",
        "track_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/track\/3s4U7OHV7gnj42VV72eSZ6",
        "track_name": "Rather Be feat. Jess Glynne",
        "artist_name": "Clean Bandit",
        "artist_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/artist\/6MDME20pz9RveH9rEXvrOM",
        "album_name": "Rather Be feat. Jess Glynne",
        "album_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/album\/4UB0J5V3JsZZtNR360pZ6r",
        "artwork_url": "http:\/\/o.scdn.co\/300\/a1babd2524962d4703a6c1aa9dfddcc2018713fd",
        "num_streams": 110491
    },
    {
        "date": "2014-05-11",
        "country": "BRA",
        "track_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/track\/3s4U7OHV7gnj42VV72eSZ6",
        "track_name": "Rather Be feat. Jess Glynne",
        "artist_name": "Clean Bandit",
        "artist_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/artist\/6MDME20pz9RveH9rEXvrOM",
        "album_name": "Rather Be feat. Jess Glynne",
        "album_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/album\/4UB0J5V3JsZZtNR360pZ6r",
        "artwork_url": "http:\/\/o.scdn.co\/300\/a1babd2524962d4703a6c1aa9dfddcc2018713fd",
        "num_streams": 17953
    },
    {
        "date": "2014-05-11",
        "country": "GBR",
        "track_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/track\/5Sf3GyLEAzJXxZ5mbCPXTu",
        "track_name": "Waves - Robin Schulz Radio Edit",
        "artist_name": "Mr. Probz",
        "artist_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/artist\/33W1pnW9zScZtYTnAoWnOT",
        "album_name": "Waves",
        "album_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/album\/7l4LGPXk2mB80WgXy4VeuB",
        "artwork_url": "http:\/\/o.scdn.co\/300\/ccfb05bea829a2dc0c736f591a22eac50c18aa56",
        "num_streams": 1401994
    },
    {
        "date": "2014-05-11",
        "country": "ITA",
        "track_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/track\/3s4U7OHV7gnj42VV72eSZ6",
        "track_name": "Rather Be feat. Jess Glynne",
        "artist_name": "Clean Bandit",
        "artist_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/artist\/6MDME20pz9RveH9rEXvrOM",
        "album_name": "Rather Be feat. Jess Glynne",
        "album_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/album\/4UB0J5V3JsZZtNR360pZ6r",
        "artwork_url": "http:\/\/o.scdn.co\/300\/a1babd2524962d4703a6c1aa9dfddcc2018713fd",
        "num_streams": 228436
    },
    {
        "date": "2014-05-11",
        "country": "USA",
        "track_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/track\/3oqCnpAoHf3SDFynxx7AU4",
        "track_name": "Fancy",
        "artist_name": "Iggy Azalea",
        "artist_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/artist\/5yG7ZAZafVaAlMTeBybKAL",
        "album_name": "Fancy",
        "album_url": "https:\/\/play.spotify.com\/album\/20a4p8pXFFG3ZungWSbYv3",
        "artwork_url": "http:\/\/o.scdn.co\/300\/62d2b5169d34280636d6f2f93f0215f50621c75e",
        "num_streams": 2877914
    }
    ],
    "prevDate": "2014-05-04"
}
```

to the output JSON that I wrote before.

This is the `parseJSON` function:

```
parseJSON = function(jsonFile){
    var tracks = {};
    var json = $.ajax({
        url: jsonFile,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: "",
        success: function(data){tracks = data.tracks;},
        async: false
    });
    console.log(tracks);
    var outputString = "{";
    for(var i = 0; i<tracks.length; i++){
        var numberOfPlays = Math.round(tracks[i].num_streams*Math.random(1000));
        var fillColor = (numberOfPlays > 5000000)? "HIGH" : (numberOfPlays < 5000000 && numberOfPlays > 1000000) ? "MEDIUM" : "LOW";
        outputString+=tracks[i].country + ":{ plays:" + numberOfPlays + ", fillKey: \"" + fillColor + "\"}";
        if (i != tracks.length-1) outputString+=",";
    }
    outputString+="}";
    console.log(outputString);
    return outputString;
}
```

I need to do this because *datamaps* expect the data to be formatted like

```
{
    COUNTRY-CODE: {
        property1: value,
        property2: value
    }
    ...
}
```

That's why using

```
d3.json("json/world-top/latest.json", function(error, latest_data) {
    if (error) {
        // Display a helpful message to the user
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log("updating");
        map.updateChoropleth(latest_data);
    }
});
```

as suggested by @James Trimble is not working too.

Comment: I am having did you found a way to parse it easly?

Comment: @Step TNT can you please post the answer that worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `parseJSON` is not available unless you are using jQuery, in which case you would use `$.parseJSON`. (JavaScript in modern browsers does have a built-in `JSON.parse` method.)

The bigger problem is that your code is trying to parse the *file name* rather than the contents of the JSON file. This is easily solved by using [d3.json](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_json) to load the data via AJAX. Here is [an example that uses this method](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3074470). The code you will need is something like:

```
d3.json("json/world-top/latest.json", function(error, latest_data) {
    if (error) {
        // Display a helpful message to the user
    } else {
        map.updateChoropleth(latest_data);
    }
});
```

An important point to remember is that the code following the `d3.json` statement will continue to run while the data is being loaded. Therefore, you need to put all of your update code within the callback function.

Comment: `parseJSON` is a function that I wrote because my JSON data has a different format from the one that *datamaps* expects. I'm updating the question to add more details.